# CSS Padding not Working?

Tags: css

Why does [the search box here](http://glamourunderground.com) not have 15px padding to the right?
This is the CSS:

```
#element_right {
padding: 120px 15px 0px 0px;
color:#161514;
font-family:helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
font-size: 13px;
background: #f4f4f4;
width: 270px;
height: 100%;
float: right;
}
```

I'm using Chrome

Comment: I can't see any similar element there? Which element on that page? This CSS looks different.

Comment: Also, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; - the Arial will never be used in your declaration.

Comment: could you share the code where you apply the style?

Comment: @Rich Yep, that is the right CSS...

Comment: @Rich Why wouldn't the Arial ever be used?

Comment: @Cornflakes ... the style might be inherited, I'm not sure - this is a template.

Comment: Because sans-serif instructs the browser to use it's default sans-serif, which will likely be Arial anyway. If you put font-family: sans-serif, Wingdings; it will render in the default sans, not Wingdings.

Comment: @Rich Oh, I see. I didn't know that. I really wanted it to be helvetica though... is it not going to use that font?

Comment: It reads from left to right until the system has the font installed. sans-serif, serif, fantasy or cursive all mean the default font, so are always matched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work (if that's what you're really trying to achieve):

```
#element_right {
padding: 120px 35px 0px 0px;
color: #161514;
font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
font-size: 13px;
background: #F4F4F4;
width: 270px;
height: 100%;
float: right;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It did work. Thank you :) But why did you put 'if that's what you're really trying to achieve'?... I'm just curious. Thanks again

Comment: Oh, I just thought because you didn't specify what the visual effect should look like :) One more note though: You should try to set up your layout so that not one `<div>` follows another, but rather inside your `wrapper` create another wrapper for the header, for the content, and for the footer. That way you can more easily control the way elements are vertically aligned. Generally, you should also rather use `margin` for achieving such an effect instead of padding, take a look at @tytsim's answer below, it's a good explanation.

Comment: I think that the different parts are called by PHP... I guess I could put divs around them, but I'm such an amateur that my approach is more of an 'If it ain't broke, don't fix it' one ;)

Answer (score 1):

To reach your effect, setting margin is a more suitable way.

Of course, it would be in conflict with the width as your child element with 280px of width break the entire structure.

I suggest you to remove the width in child element and make width effect at #element_right with a 295px of width the same with boxes below.

So the search box's width and horizontal position would exactly be identical to the boxes below besides the border and box shadow.

**EDIT:** Delete misleading answer.

Comment: Thanks @tytsim I understand what you mean, but I'm trying to get the width to be the same as the boxes below it so it looks more uniform.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your meaning. Anyway, to reach your effect, setting margin is a more suitable way. Of course, it would be in conflict with the width as your child element with 280px of width break the entire structure. I suggest you to remove the width in child element and make width effect at #element_right with a 295px of width the same with boxes below. So the search box's width and horizontal position would exactly be identical to the boxes below besides the border and box shadow. Hope I haven't misunderstand you again. Apologize for my terrible grammar and frequently modification.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the contents of the search div doesn't leave room for padding, Shrink your input to width:190px

Comment: Ok, do you know which width I should shrink..?

Answer (score 0):

Just check with opera, and your 15px padding works, you are just filling it with the search bar